# Force Audio for Browser?

Tags: macos, audio

I am interested in Google Voice, but the lack of a real client for OSX is annoying. If I could get a particular browser to talk to a particular audio device (my wireless headset), I'd be happy. Is there any way to force certain programs to use a particular output/input?

Comment: You could always try the products by Rogue Amoeba. Unfortunately, I only have my internal speakers right now. Airfoil looked somewhat good (redirect browser to computer, maybe you can select a specific speaker then?), and in *Audio Hijack » Advanced*, I was able to send one program's output to just a single speaker, while the rest went to both speakers. No answer, as I was unable to try it myself. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for much @Daniel Beck, with multiple audio destinations hijack doesn't seem to help. I'm going to mess around with aggregate audio devices next. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Talk in the browser allows you to pick your audio drivers (in settings) for the phone. This does not answer the question of how to force audio for the browser, but it does solve the problem of how to use Google Voice with a particular audio driver.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Voice Mac](http://mrgeckosmedia.com/applications/info/VoiceMac), an Integrated Google Voice Client described in this article :
[Voice Mac is an Integrated Google Voice Client](http://lifehacker.com/#!5391896/voice-mac-is-an-integrated-google-voice-client).

The developer's site seems down at the moment, but Voice Mac can also be found [here](http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/Voice-Mac-Download-61161.html).

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. I had found that the other day, but I cannot find a working copy of the app, and I try to avoid obsoleteware. You would think that Google would actually make a non-browser client... GTalk as a "phone" is 100% annoying.

Comment: Whatever works is fine. Some applications I still use are obsoleteware or abandonware.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but Voice Mac does not let you make calls. It lets you "place" calls through one of your Google Voice devices, like your cell phone or GTalk in the browser.

Comment: I wouldn't know. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a flash application, if you right click on it and click "Settings", there's a microphone tab and a camera tab where you can select the devices you wish to use.

Comment: Interesting point, but I don't think Google Voice is a Flash app.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the output for the sound device via the sound preference pane in         `System Preferences.app` or <kbd>option</kbd>-clicking the volume icon in the menubar. However, this is for the whole OS, and not only for the browser.